# Solve syntax error "unexpected identifier dmap" with visual studio express 2012

Tags: c++, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

I am compiling Palabos with visual studio 2012.
I get the following error:

Warning  1   warning C4346: 'plb::ExtractDynamicsChainFunctional2D::DMap' : dependent name is not a type   c:\users\max\desktop\drawing\c++\palabos\src\dataprocessors\metastufffunctional2d.hh    100 1   Drawing

Error   2   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'DMap'   c:\users\max\desktop\drawing\c++\palabos\src\dataprocessors\metastufffunctional2d.hh    100 1   Drawing

The code causing this error is:

```
/* ******** ExtractDynamicsChainFunctional2D ************************************ */
template<typename T, template<typename U> class Descriptor>
ExtractDynamicsChainFunctional2D<T,Descriptor>::ExtractDynamicsChainFunctional2D (
        ExtractDynamicsChainFunctional2D<T,Descriptor>::DMap const& dynamicsMap_,
        pluint maxChainSize_ )
    : dynamicsMap(dynamicsMap_),
      maxChainSize(maxChainSize_)
{ }
```

My knowledge of c++ is very limited. Can somebody explain what is causing this error, and how I can fix it.

Comment: try `typename ExtractDynamicsChainFunctional2D<T,Descriptor>::DMap`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means: `ExtractDynamicsChainFunctional2D<T,Descriptor>::DMap` is by default *not* a type and cannot be used as such. If you want it to be recognised as a type, you have to put `typename` in front of it.

The problem occurs only inside a templated code, where you want to access a member type of another template.